# need XAML tutorial

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I am new to Silverlight.

I need a tutorial which helps me understand XAML styling,resources and object binding to a UI.

Please suggest any books or links. thanks

Comment: (note: dnt need msdn as i have already been through still i am confuse with the concepts) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codingconvention.com/tutorials/Silverlight-XAML

http://silverlightcorner.blogspot.in/2012/01/wpf-data-binding-tutorial-1.html

http://xamlandmore.blogspot.in/

Hope these will help...!!!

Comment: http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html


here you will find samples for different controls

Comment: I am going through your link. once i get complete with it. i will post any query or confusion if i get in. thanks in advance

Comment: yup @Abhishek, queries are welcome in SO...!!!

Comment: are their any books available online for XAML?

Comment: you mean downloadble e-books?

Comment: http://interview-development.blogspot.in/2011/11/silverlight-e-books.html

Answer (score 2):

http://www.wpftutorial.net/XAML.html

It will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This may be very useful...

http://silverlighttutorials.blogspot.in/

http://www.smashingapps.com/2009/05/02/15-excellent-and-useful-microsoft-silverlight-tutorials-resources.html

Detailed explanation of features with sample code..

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=735