# How do you hard-code a text editor in Visual C# or Visual Basic (both being 2010) express editions, using a screen reader for the blind?

Tags: c#

```
  System.Console.WriteLine("Hello StackOverflow folks!");
```

I would like to know how to hard-code a text editor using either the language I just used or Visual Basic, utilizing the Visual Studio IDE. I know there is a GUI designer but I am using a screen reader for the blind, so dragging and dropping controls is not an easy task. I have looked for this on the Internet, narrowing down my search to my situation but I cannot find anything. Would you guys be so kind and help me find a tutorial about hard-coding a text editor?
I would really appreciate it!
Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: I'm not sure you know what "hard-coding" means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll tell you up front: I have no experience with using a screen reader. But I do know that I program without ever using the GUI designer in Visual Studio. It is easier if you use Visual Studio 2008, 2010, or the newest 2012 Release Candidate (currently a free download, with conditions). If you use those IDEs, you can use the Windows Presentation Foundation Platform, which gains you access to XAML. This markup language will allow you to create rich GUIs without the need for drag and drop. True, you can create Windows Forms applications in pure code-behind (using C# or Visual Basic), but that would be a pain. Here are some basic tutorials for XAML and WPF programming:

http://wpftutorial.net/XAML.html

http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/wpfintro.htm (Visual Basic)

[need XAML tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749625/need-xaml-tutorial) (A question that has answers with plenty of tutorials)

I wish you the best!

Comment: Hi JohnI'm just looking at this answer, and would like to tell you that I think your wishes came served me well, because I was able to present a GUI application to a pannel during my senior project. Thanks for your help, and wish that deeds like these are repaid for you.